# How would you go on to prove that the functions $f(t) = e^t$ , $g(t)=\sin (t)$ are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having some difficulties understanding an example given in a lecture about linearly dependent and independent sets.

the example has been solved by investigating what $t=0$ and $t=\pi$ give when plugged in $ x_1 f(t)+x_2 g(t)$ (which is $x_1=0$) then what $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$ gives, and that is later solved to find that $x_1=0$ and $x_2=0$.

I do not understand why we summed both functions when we could have investigated what the scalar would be in $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ separately!

Comment: Please explain the sentence "we could have investigated what the scalar would be in $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ separately!" Given $n$ elements $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ of a vector space, we say that they are *linearly independent* if the zero vector $\bf 0$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ in only one way, namely: $\textbf{0} = 0v_1+0v_2+\cdots+0v_n$.

Comment: Anyway, the linear independence is obvious if one observes that linear dependence would imply $\sin t$ has a constant sign.